# Error using "npm" command on Node 14.X versions. 'timers/promises' module not found

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules, nvm

Only on node 14.X I have this problem. I basically can't run any npm command when switching to Node 14 using nvm.

Im trying to run a gatsby proyect that was working fine until 1 week ago. It needs a node 14 version to run correctly for dependency issues. I was cleaning my PC and erased visual studio, but installed it again cuz it could be the problem.

When I Try to npm install with other node versions, the node-sass dependency shows errors. I updated to be compatible to my current Node version but then other errors appear

I have reinstalled all node and nvm versions. Checked paths and all seems ok. Tried different Node 14.XX versions too. Nothing works.I just can't seem to use "npm" at all.

The error is:
Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'

[Terminal full error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrmCs.png)